# apache dies when I FTP to server as that user

Tags: ftp, apache-httpd

I have an odd one.  A RedHat 7 server, with an apache server that runs just fine. I can start it with `systemctl start httpd`.  Developers had me run it as a different user (intersys instead of apache).  Now when I FTP to the server as that user, (intersys) actually when I disconnect the FTP session, it kills httpd.
I see this error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Mon Mar 21 10:02:49.308506 2016] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 13734] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Mon Mar 21 10:02:49.611064 2016] [core:alert] [pid 12683] AH00050: Child 13726 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
```

I have tried changing the shell of "intersys" to various things, no help.

restart always works fine.  I think something is sending `httpd` a hangup signal.  any ideas about how to stop that?

Comment: For reference, mention the version of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Mutex` directive within `httpd.conf` is set to `pthread`, try changing it to `fcntl`.

Comment: where do I set AcceptMutex?  This is apache 2.4, I dont' see that parameter in 2.4 .

Comment: I have tried various things as the shell for "intersys":  /sbin/nologin, /bint/true. /bin/bash.  all give the same result.

Comment: If this is not set the default value is loaded, just specify AcceptMutex fcntl in the httpd.conf and test again.

Comment: For Apache 2.4 the declaration is "Mutex". http://serverfault.com/questions/755823/permission-denied-couldn-t-grab-the-accept-mutex

Comment: Oh, my fault, will edit now.